# Having trouble finding the text of google search result

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to use BeautifulSoup to find the text of each search result on [google](http://google.com/search?q=world%20news). Using the developer tools, I can see that this is represented by a `<h3>` with the `class` " LC20lb DKV0Md ".

However I cant seem find this using BeautifulSoup. What am I doing wrong?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('http://google.com/search?q=world+news')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all('h3', class_= 'LC201b DKV0Md')
```

Comment: The class name you’re using is likely dynamically generated on each page load - every time you make a request for the page, the class of the element you’re looking for will likely be different. Find another way to target the element you’re looking for.

Comment: use xpath to target the element

Comment: I don't think that's the case because the `class` name never changes no matter how many times I reload the page or even if I search for something else.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with xpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to search by `class`, you simply can `select` all `<h3>` that includes a `<div>` and than `get_text()` of each:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('http://google.com/search?q=world+news')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')

[x.get_text() for x in soup.select('h3 div')]
```

Output:

```
['World - BBC News',
 'BBC News World',
 'Latest news from around the world | The Guardian',
 'World - breaking news, videos and headlines - CNN',
 'CNN International - Breaking News, US News, World News and Video',
 'Welt-Nachrichten',
 'BBC World News (Fernsehsender)',
 'World News - Breaking international news and headlines | Sky News',
 'International News | Latest World News, Videos & Photos -ABC',
 'World News Headlines | Reuters',
 'World News - Hindustan Times',
 'World News | International Headlines - Breaking World - Global News']
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly for me but just out of curiosity, what was I doing wrong with respect to the `class` name ? Someone mentioned that the class is likely being dynamically generated with each page load. But I've checked several times and it is always the same `class` name so I'm at a loss. Also, searching by `class` works perfectly for me on other sites but I cant get it to work on Google.

Comment: There is nothing wrong to deal with the `class` in other projects - If you take a look in your soup - code will differ from the developer tools `<h3 class="zBAuLc"><div class="BNeawe vvjwJb AP7Wnd">World - BBC News</div></h3>` The text is not in the `h3`it is in a `div`

Answer (score 0):

If you having difficulties figuring out which element to use, have a look at [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension, it's easier and faster than searching through dev tools. However, it does not always work perfectly if the website is rendered via JavaScript.

> find the text of each search result on [google](http://google.com/search?q=world%20news).

Assuming that you meant "from all pages", you can scrape Google Search Results information from all pages using `while True` loop i,e pagination.

The while loop is an endless loop that will dynamically be paginating to the next page if `.d6cvqb a[id=pnnext]` selector is present which is responsible for the "next page" button:

```py
if soup.select_one('.d6cvqb a[id=pnnext]'):
        params["start"] += 10 # increment a URL parameter that controls page number
else:
    break
```

Keep in mind that the request may be blocked if you're using `requests` as the default `user-agent in requests` library is a [`python-requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814).

To avoid it, one of the steps could be to [rotate `user-agent`](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/#rotate-user-agents), for example, to switch between PC, mobile, and tablet, as well as between browsers e.g. Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge and so on.

Check code in [online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-google-search-results-with-pagination#main.py).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, lxml

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls
params = {
    "q": "world+news",   # query
    "hl": "en",          # language
    "gl": "us",          # country of the search, US -> USA
    "start": 0,          # number page by default up to 0
    #"num": 100          # parameter defines the maximum number of results to return.
}

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

page_num = 0

website_data = []

while True:
    page_num += 1
    print(f"page: {page_num}")
        
    html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
    
    for result in soup.select(".tF2Cxc"):
        title = result.select_one(".DKV0Md").text
        website_link = result.select_one(".yuRUbf a")["href"]
                    
        website_data.append({
              "title": title,
              "website_link": website_link  
        })
      
    if soup.select_one('.d6cvqb a[id=pnnext]'):
        params["start"] += 10
    else:
        break

print(json.dumps(website_data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Example output:

```json
[
    {
    "title": "World news – breaking news, videos and headlines - CNN",
    "website_link": "https://www.cnn.com/world"
  },
  {
    "title": "World - BBC News",
    "website_link": "https://www.bbc.com/news/world"
  },
  {
    "title": "Latest news from around the world | The Guardian",
    "website_link": "https://www.theguardian.com/world"
  },
  {
    "title": "World News Headlines | Reuters",
    "website_link": "https://www.reuters.com/news/archive/worldNews"
  },
  {
    "title": "World - NBC News",
    "website_link": "https://www.nbcnews.com/world"
  },
  # ...
]
```

---

Also you can use [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with the free plan.
The difference is that it will bypass blocks (including CAPTCHA) from Google, no need to create the parser and maintain it.

Code example:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, parse_qsl
import json, os

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"), # serpapi key
  "engine": "google",              # serpapi parser engine
  "q": "world+news",               # search query
  "num": "100"                     # number of results per page (100 per page in this case)
  # other search parameters: https://serpapi.com/search-api#api-parameters
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)      # where data extraction happens

organic_results_data = []
page_num = 0

while True:
    results = search.get_dict()    # JSON -> Python dictionary
    
    page_num += 1
    
    for result in results["organic_results"]:
        organic_results_data.append({
            "title": result.get("title") 
        })
    
    if "next_link" in results.get("serpapi_pagination", []):
        search.params_dict.update(dict(parse_qsl(urlsplit(results.get("serpapi_pagination").get("next_link")).query)))
    else:
        break
    
print(json.dumps(organic_results_data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Output:

```json
[
   {
    "title": "World news – breaking news, videos and headlines - CNN"
  },
  {
    "title": "World - BBC News"
  },
  {
    "title": "Latest news from around the world | The Guardian"
  },
  {
    "title": "World News Headlines | Reuters"
  },
  {
    "title": "World - NBC News"
  },
  # ...
]
```